# Set datagridview cell value to index number of row c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I would like my code to loop through all rows in my datagridview and set the first column value in each row to the row index number of itself. My code so far does not work. Any help appreciated.

```
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            this.DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value = e.RowIndex + 1;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    foreach (var row in dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>())
    {
        dgv[0, row.Index].Value = row.Index;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this code does not compile.

Comment: RowPrePaint event of DGV

Comment: RowIndex is underscored red. The error is 'dgv' does not contain a definition for 'RowIndex'. I have replaced dgv with the name of my dgv of course.

Comment: Your solution worked! Thanks so very much for spending time to help me.